# use onClick not possible

Tags: javascript, animation, html, move

I have 2 divs and 1 iframe div. So, i just need to add animation to move this divs to the left, and i don't know how, because i have already onClick. Could you help me?

```
<div id="page3" onClick='document.getElementById("ifr").src="text2.html";'>2</div>
<div id="page1" onClick='document.getElementById("ifr").src="text1.html";'>1</div>
<div id="middlediv"><iframe id='ifr' width='100%' height='100%' src="text1.html"</iframe></div>
```

Thank you a lot!!!

So, now i have this java code:

```
function proc1(){
wwidth=window.innerWidth;
wheight=window.innerHeight;
document.getElementById('rightdiv').style.height=wheight-200-10+'px';
document.getElementById('leftdiv').style.height=wheight-200-10+'px';
document.getElementById('middlediv').style.height=wheight-200-10+'px';
document.getElementById('middlediv').style.width=wwidth-200-10+'px';
}
function MoveGridLeft()
{
   $('#page3').animate({
   'marginLeft' : "+=50px"
   });
 }
```

and this script stroke `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js" src="1.js">`
1.js has a code that is above. Animation doesn't work, and scripts doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can call two function in one event

```
onClick='document.getElementById("ifr").src="text2.html"; MoveGridLeft();'
```

jQuery function to move

```
function MoveGridLeft()
{
   $('#page3').animate({
   'marginLeft' : "-=50px"
   });
 }
```

Updated:

Download jQuery file from this [link](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js) and add the reference to the project as:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`

Here is the [article](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-vs-jquery-animations/) which explains how to use CSS3 to animate.

Comment: so, jquery it's a library ? i just need to download it?

Comment: If you're adding a whole library for this, then you might as well move to unobtrusive JavaScript at the same time.

Comment: i know it, the problem it's that i have a javascript in 1 html file, so i can't make it work, i need to load java from another file, but i need all in 1 file, i know it's stupid, but...

Comment: if you dnt want to go for jquery , you can use css3 to animate the divs

Comment: so i have function proc1(){
wwidth=window.innerWidth;
wheight=window.innerHeight;
//alert(wwidht+''+wheight)
document.getElementById('rightdiv').style.height=wheight-200-10+'px';

document.getElementById('leftdiv').style.height=wheight-200-10+'px';




document.getElementById('middlediv').style.height=wheight-200-10+'px';

document.getElementById('middlediv').style.width=wwidth-200-10+'px';
}
function MoveGridLeft()
{
   $('#page3').animate({
   'marginLeft' : "+=50px"
   });
 }

Comment: Note: this current answer's payload `'marginLeft' : "+=50px"` animates a div to the *right* instead of animating it to the left.

Answer (score 0):

All javascript code in inline handlers like `onclick` is automatically wrapped in a function, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10607847/588079) on SO.

So, there is no reason why you can't add extra statements (or function-calls in this case), like:
`onclick="document.getElementById('ifr').src='text1.html'; moveDivLeft();"`

**Update** (to your updated question):

- Java has *nothing* to do with EcmaScript dialects like javascript.
- The (JQuery dependent) function `MoveGridLeft` that you copied from [Shafqat Masood's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16263706/588079) increases the *left margin*, so it moves the div to the *right* instead of moving it to the *left*. Depending on your code you would need to set the correct properties (like left|right position|margin) to achieve your goal (taking in account your existing markup/layout/style). Have a look at this *example* jsfiddle based on all your comments (below this question): [jsfiddle.net/t74fT/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/t74fT/3/)
- The line: `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js" src="1.js">` is wrong: you gave it 2 sources which is not valid markup.
  Each (external) script gets it's own script-tag, like:
  `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>`
  `<script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>`
  Note that now you have 3 files instead of just 1 like you originally asked.

Comment: Ok, i undterstood, but can i make it with pure javascript?

Comment: given your question I figured you'd knew how to 'animate' the div's but didn't know how to hook it up using `onclick`. But you need a pure javascript animation now? Maybe update your question to tell us more about what and how (and how fast etc.) you want to animate.

Comment: a problem that i have just 1 html file, and <script></script> on it, so i can't load jquery...no, it's ok now, i will find how to animate myself, thanks.

Comment: You can have multiple script tags inside one html-document! So something like this is perfectly valid: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">alert('another script');</script>`  Have a look at [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_animation.htm) to get you started with pure javascript animations (using `setTimeout(function, duration);` or `setInterval(function, duration);`)

Comment: and now it doesn't work( <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js" src="1.js"></script>

Comment: here is my java function proc1(){
wwidth=window.innerWidth;
wheight=window.innerHeight;
//alert(wwidht+''+wheight)
document.getElementById('rightdiv').style.height=wheight-200-10+'px';

document.getElementById('leftdiv').style.height=wheight-200-10+'px';




document.getElementById('middlediv').style.height=wheight-200-10+'px';

document.getElementById('middlediv').style.width=wwidth-200-10+'px';
}
function MoveGridLeft()
{
   $('#page3').animate({
   'marginLeft' : "+=50px"
   });
 }

Comment: 'java function'? Don't you mean javascript? Note that java has nothing to do with javascript.

Comment: So you meant: `here is my javascript: function proc1(){ etc...` instead of `here is my java function proc1(){ etc..`?    What are `rightdiv` and `leftdiv` ?  Could it be that you mean `page1` and `page3`?     There are also typo's in the code you gave in your comment like `wwidht`.     Based on everything you gave us, I did this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7Lrb/) for you. Stuff is moving with jquery.

Comment: i have 5 divs, top, bottom, left,right, middle, so i have iframe in the middle, and buttons( div page1,3) in the bottom, but i can't make it work...animation doesn't work, and when i loading 1.js, site is loading bad, because script doesn't work, so it's worked only when i putted it at <script></script> but i can't do that because of jquery....

Comment: add/modify the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7Lrb/) I provided so we can see your problem and layout (click 'run' to test, 'update' to update and post us back the updated link). Also, you might want to re-read my comments as they should address your multiple script / jquery problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t74fT/1/ here is without iframe contet, because it's in other files.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t74fT/2/   First: `<body onload="proc1();"> onresize="proc1();">` is wrong, should have been: `<body onload="proc1();" onresize="proc1();">` but I just added `window.onresize=function(){ proc1(); };`. Secondly, you where calling `MoveGridLeft()` while the function was called `moveGridLeft()` (first letter as a capital is commonly reserved for objects). Finally, the copy-paste code didn't work because (it was/is unclear what you want to achieve exactly and) if you look at function `moveGridLeft` you see it tries to *increase* `marginLeft` *and* your div's are css-positioned!

Comment: Can't you nest divs `page1` and `page3` (acting as link/button) inside your footer wrapper? That would make things a lot more simple!

Comment: how can i make it a button? ( i mean, to save work the buttons, to save iframe?)

Comment: and movegridleft it's smoothly animate the buttons? or they just jump to the new position? because i need a slow animation..

Comment: As an example an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t74fT/3/    Your spaces are illegal in an `id`, so I removed your html: `<div id="bottomdiv div"></div>`. In the css there is still a `#bottomdiv div` rule: that targets all divs (the buttons that I moved) inside your `bottomdiv`. If you now click `2` (the grey 'button' div with id 'page3') you'll see all buttons (divs) move to the left. A button is done like: `<button onclick="yourCodeHere">caption</button>`. I suspect you ultimately want to do javascript [carousel](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+carousel).

Comment: it's great, thank you, but anyway, it's moving page1 element, not page3, and my bottom it's doesn't resizing anymore...

Comment: About the resizing: your fiddle v2 has the bottom-div set (in css) to 100px. It never resized. In my **example** fiddle (that solves the clear questions you've asked and demonstrates the smooth animation of) all 'buttons' (so div id 'page1' and 'page3') move to the left (you asked: '*move this divs to the left*') if you click button `2` (aka div id page3). Until you exactly describe the behavior (of the buttons) you are after, we can't write (guessing) specific (pure javascript) code/examples. However you now do have working examples so you could code your own behavior like you want it to.

Comment: heh, i don't know why, but it works....http://jsfiddle.net/t74fT/5/ in my computer doesn't...

Comment: You still have this `<div id="bottomdiv div"></div>` That's not a valid id!!!  What do you mean by '*in my computer doesn't*'

Comment: so, it works, thank you a lot!=) i don't know why, buy it's moving)