# difference between alert("Hi!") and function(){alert("Hi!")}

Tags: javascript, dom

When we are doing inline command in the button:

```
<button id="myButton" onclick="alert('Hi!')">
```

Why does

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = alert('Hi!')
```

not work but give the alert as the page is loaded? I can't understand how it works with `function()` added to it and without `function()`. I hope you guys understand my question. I'm missing something here.

Comment: One executes immediately and then gives the result; the other creates a function that -- when the function is invoked will perform that behavior -- and returns the function (not the execution of its body).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = alert('Hi!')
```

is wrong since onclick should be assigned to a function reference, not the function call result itself.

It will execute  `alert('Hi!')` when the page is loaded but that is not the intention here, is it? The intention behind assigning an onclick handler is to ensure that when the button is clicked this alert will be executed.

For that to happen it should be:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function(){alert('Hi!')};
```

Also, this will not work unless it is wrapped inside the `window.onload` event:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function(){alert('Hi!')};
};
```

Comment: document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = alert('Hi!'), if this expects a function reference why does it not throw error instead it just alerts whenever the page is loaded..

Comment: @3yK It will not throw an error at page load, only at button click. Since when the button click happens only then a function call onclick() will be made which will get translated to `(alert("hi'))()`. At page load it will simply execute alert(Hi).

Comment: @3yK check the updated answer as well.

Comment: @gurvinder372 just to be clear, if you put your `<script>` at the end of the body tag, you don't need to wrap the code in `window.onload`, right ? Or is it still bad practice ?

Comment: @Apolo I would still keep it in `window.onload` for two reasons 1) so that my code is not too much dependent on where it is on a page 2) you don't have to worry about your collegue copying this code (which was working in this location) to somewhere else and then complain to you that your code hasn't worked. Pretty much all the reasons why we follow best-practices :)

Comment: @gurvinder372 Two good points, thanks

Comment: @3yK specifically, it will run `alert("hi")` to see what that returns (it returns `undefined`), and stores _that_ in the onclick handler. When you click it, it then calls `undefined()` and because that's not a valid function it causes an error.

Answer (score 10):

`alert('Hi!')` is a function **call** that alerts 'Hi' and returns nothing (`undefined`).

`onclick` expects to get a function and you are passing the function call's result which is `undefined`.

Since `JavaScript` is not a strong typed framework you don't get an error on bad assignments.

So why does the following work:

```
<button id = "myButton" onclick="alert('Hi!')">
```

It's because the html parser (in this case, your browser) does some work behind the scenes and wraps the call with a function.

Comment: Not sure how angular reference is relevant here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Just an example that shows how parsers and frameworks know how to handle html "javascript" expressions in a different way.

Comment: Given that the OP doesn't know angular and how it works, this doesn't help a bit, I think.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - The OP can stick with the first explanation. The other people who maybe will enter this link in the future may benefit from the latter.

Answer (score 7):

`document.getElementById("myButton").onclick` expects a function to be called later.

`<button id = "myButton "onclick="alert('Hi!')">` expects a block of code to be executed later.

Answer (score 6):

```
alert('Hi')
```

Here **alert** is an inbuilt function called by browser which opens a alert box.

```
function callAlert(){
  alert('Hi');
}
```

Here **callAlert** is a custom function which calls the inbuilt function **alert**

In your example, when appending a click event, you have to **define** the function

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = alert('Hi!') //alert is
```

already executed

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function (){ alert('Hi!') }; 
//a function is defined/declared which will be executed when the onclick action is performed
```

Answer (score 5):

See [this post for explanation for why the inline version works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607847/how-does-inline-javascript-in-html-work).

In short, the browser doesn't just assign `alert('Hi!')` to `onclick` but instead wraps it in a function.