# Are inline JavaScript event child tags supported in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Here we have a div with a onclick handler:

```
<div id="BorderContainer1282" onclick="alert('hello')">
    <input id="Button925" type="button" value="Button">
</div >
```

When clicked it shows an alert dialog.

Does HTML support inline JavaScript in a child tag of the same name, like so:

```
<div id="BorderContainer1282">
    <onclick>alert('hello');</onclick>
    <input id="Button925" type="button" value="Button">
</div >
```

This question is not best practices. It is specifically about HTML supports setting events in a child tag of an HTML element as shown in the example.

NOTE: I tested the code above in example 2 and it does not work in my tests.

If it does not work, would using the following template be an acceptable alternative:

```
<div id="BorderContainer1282">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('BorderContainer1282').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            (function(event) {
                alert('hello');
            }).call(document.getElementById("BorderContainer1282"), event);
        });
    </script>
    <input id="Button925" type="button" value="Button">
</div >
```

Again, I'm not concerned about best practices now, only if this feature is supported.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607847/how-does-inline-javascript-in-html-work) that is not a duplicate.

Comment: `<onclick>` tag ? It's already ugly as an attribute but that... Ps: never seen this in HTML, but maybe some long long time ago ? PPs : what the purpose of the `call()` in your latest example?

Comment: I think the call causes the `this` reference to refer to the HTML element rather than another object.

Comment: wrong guess, `this` refers to the object on which the event has been attached. Here you are calling 'undefined' (the result of `addEventListener()`)

Comment: ok it should be using call on the anonymous function. maybe i have a missing parameter. i'll update it.

Comment: Defining custom tags is supported in HTML, as you do with your `<onclick>` tag.  Browsers tend to treat these as inline elements unless you style them differently, and the text you put within will be displayed.  Be aware that older browsers require a `document.createElement("onclick")` in the `<head>` before you can use it. Of course, clicking on the tag / its parent / some element(s) around which it's wrapped will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is not valid HTML; there is no `<onclick>` tag. The reason you are able to execute JavaScript in the first example is because of [Event attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Event_attributes) for certain tags.

These attributes allow you to execute arbitrary JavaScript when a certain event is triggered on the given element, and although you are not concerned with best practices here, you should avoid using them if you want to keep your markup clean and organized.

What you are looking for is the `<script>` tag in your third example, which does allow for the insertion of JavaScript anywhere in your HTML markup, and is what you should use in this case. You can use this tag and [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach an event handler to your `div`. This is the proper usage of the tag in this scenario:

```
<div id="BorderContainer1282">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("BorderContainer1282").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            alert("Hello!");
        });
    </script>
    <input id="Button925" type="button" value="Button">
</div >
```

Lastly, `<script>` tags are typically placed at the end of the `<body>` to ensure that all elements have been loaded before the script executes. You can also accomplish this by wrapping your JavaScript in a `window.addEventListener("load", function(){ ... });`.

Comment: If the script is placed after the element has been declared OP will be fine.

Comment: The second example is valid HTML. The third example *uses* a `<script>` tag already. A `load` even on `window` runs far later than necessary, since only the `document` needs to be fully loaded, and either way, you can have latency issues, which can be solved by using an attribute.