# Direct DOM manipulation or access

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Look at this code:

```
<div>
   <p onClick="parentNode.remove()">click me</p>
</div>
```

Is it accessing dom via js.

I saw similar example example somewhere and it worked.

1. How is it possible without js or is it somehow javascript
2. Will it work if js is disabled in browser.
3. Where can I look for similar functions. mozilla's dom api docs were not very helpful for me as I could not even find that parentNode.remove()  function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does inline Javascript (in HTML) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607847/how-does-inline-javascript-in-html-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is "somehow" javascript.
2. No. It's legit js so it will not work.
3. [ParentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/ParentNode)
   [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

   You can look at this question
   for clarification [How does inline Javascript (in HTML) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607847/how-does-inline-javascript-in-html-work)